Internal product of Exterior algebras.
Let $V=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z} \cdot e_i$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $n$ and $\Lambda V$ the exterior algebra of $V$. We can define a product $\Lambda V \odot \Lambda V$ of dimension $3^n$ that has the property that $(\alpha \wedge e_i) \odot( \beta \wedge e_i)=0$ for all $\alpha,\beta \in \Lambda V$ and basis vectors $e_i \in V$. It's not hard to see that basis vectors are in one-to-one correspondence to maps $\{1, \dots, n\} \to \{-1,0,1\}$. Of course, this definition depends on the choice of basis.
Q: Are you aware of a more universal construction of this $3$-ary analogue of the exterior algebra?

Edit:
Probably a bit nicer is the following definition: let $B$ denote the ordered basis of $V$. Then $M(V) = \bigoplus_{S \subseteq B} \Lambda (V_S) $ where $V_S \leq V$ is the submodule spanned by $S$. Still dependent on the basis.
If used vector spaces instead of free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, I think a coordinate independent construction could be
$$
M(V) = \left( \bigoplus_{W \leq V} \Lambda (W)  \right) / \sim,
$$
where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation induced by the obvious $GL(n)$-action. However, I am actually rather looking for a definition via a universal property - in the best case one that makes some algebraic structure apparent. Similar to the external algebra, which is a universal quotient of the tensor algebra, inheriting the algebra structure.

@Balajisb That's too strong a condition, unfortunately

I have expanded a bit on the example I used at the end of my answer to explain why I think this implies there cannot be a universal construction of $\odot$. (This is contingent on deciding what you want that to mean, and I have chosen the most elementary interpretation I can think of!)

Are you sure you want to take $\bigoplus_{W \leq V}$, rather than, say, imposing the condition that $V/W$ is torsion-free? If you don't impose something like that, then the object you get is a lot bigger than what you had before.

@krm2233 You are right that on the level of equality it can't be defined coordinate free. I was actually rather thinking of a definition by universal property up to isomorphism (see my edit). Sorry if I was not clear enough before.

@krm2233 ah I forgot that I used free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules rather than vector spaces :D Thx for pointing it out!

@Balajisb see the example in krm2233's answer

With apologies that a lot of this may be obvious (I just wanted to check the details:
Recall that the exterior algebra $\bigwedge\!{^*(}V) = \bigoplus_{k=0}^n \bigwedge\!{^k(}V)$ where $\bigwedge\!{^k(}V)$ has basis $e_I = e_{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e_{i_k}$ for $I=(i_1<i_2<\ldots< i_k)$ a $k$-element subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Thus $\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)$ has a basis  $\{e_I: I\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}\}$ (where if $\emptyset$ denotes the emptyset then $e_\emptyset=1$) and hence has dimension $2^n$.
Now $\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\odot \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)$ is the quotient of $\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\otimes \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)$ by the $\mathbb Z$-submodule spanned by
$$
\{(\alpha\wedge e_i)\otimes(\beta\wedge e_i), \alpha,\beta \in \bigwedge\!{^*(}V), i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}\}.
$$
Thus if  we take $\alpha_1 = e_I$ and $\beta_1 = e_J$ for subsets $I$ and $J$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and consider $e_I\odot e_J$, then it follows that this is zero unless $I\cap J = \emptyset$: indeed if $i_0 \in I\cap J$, then $e_I = \pm e_{I_0}\wedge e_{i_0}$ and $e_J =\pm e_{J_0}\wedge e_{i_0}$ where $I_0 = I\backslash \{i_0\}$ and $J_0 = J\backslash\{i_0\}$ and the sign is determined by how many elements of $I$ (resp. $J$) are greater than $i_0$. But then $e_I\odot e_J = \pm e_{I_0}\wedge e_{i_0}\odot e_{J_0}\wedge e_{i_0} =0$.
It follows that $\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\odot\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)$ is spanned by the element $e_I\odot e_J$ where $I\cap J = \emptyset$. Now if we write $\mathbb F_3$ for $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z =\{0,1,-1\}$, then the set
$$
\{(I,J): I,J \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}, I\cap J=\emptyset\}
$$
is in bijection with $\{1,0,-1\}^n =\mathbb F_3^n$ where if $\phi\colon \{1,\ldots,n\} \to \{1,0,-1\}$ we let $I = \phi^{-1}(1)$ and $J = \phi^{-1}(-1)$.
To see that $\{e_I\odot e_J: I\cap J = \emptyset, I,J\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}\}$ is actually a basis - that is, to show it is linearly independent - seems a little less trivial to me, but for example one can show this as follows: let $A=\mathbb Z[\mathbb F_3^n]$ be the group algebra of the abelian group $(\mathbb F_3^n,+)$. We will write elements of $A$ as $\sum_{\mathbf a \in \mathbb F_3^n} c_\mathbf a e^{\mathbf a}$, $(c_\mathbf a \in \mathbb Z, \forall \mathbf a \in \mathbb F_3^n$) so that the addition and multiplication on $A$ are given on $e^{\mathbf a}$ and $e^{\mathbf b}$ by $e^{\mathbf a}+e^{\mathbf b}$ and $e^{\mathbf a+\mathbf b}$ respectively.
Now define a pairing on
$$
\langle -,-\rangle : A\times \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\otimes \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\to \mathbb Z
$$ as follows: We define $\delta_{A,B}$ to $0$ if $A\neq B$ and $1$ if $A=B$. Since $\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\otimes \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)$ has basis $\{e_I\otimes e_J: I,J\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}\}$ and $A$ has basis $\{e^{\mathbf a}: \mathbf a \in \mathbb F^n_3\}$ a pairing is uniquely determined by specifying
$$
\langle e^{\mathbf a},e_I\otimes e_J\rangle = \delta_{I,\mathbf a^{-1}(1)}\delta_{J,\mathbf a^{-1}(-1)}
$$
where $\mathbf a^{-1}(1) = \{i: 1\leq i\leq n, a_i=1\}$ and $\mathbf a^{-1}(-1)=\{i: 1\leq i \leq n, a_i=-1\}$. Since this pairing contains $(\alpha\wedge e_i)\otimes (\beta\wedge e_i)$ in its (right) radical, it descends to a pairing
$$
\langle -,-\rangle: A\times \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\odot \bigwedge\!{^*(}V) \to \mathbb Z
$$
Now $A$ is free of rank $3^n$ by construction, and under the pairing the set $\{e_I\odot e_J: I\cap J = \emptyset\}$ is dual to the basis $\{e^{\mathbf a}: \mathbf a \in \mathbb F^n_3\}$ of $A$ via the correspondence
$$
e_I\odot e_J \leftrightarrow e^{\mathbf a_{I,J}}, \text{ where } \mathbf a_{I,J}(k)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \text{if } k \in I;\\
-1, & \text{if } k \in J;\\
0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{array}\right.
$$
it follows that $\{e_I\odot e_J: I\cap J = \emptyset\}$ are linearly independent.
Thus one could generalise this construction to $\bigodot^m \bigwedge\!{^*(}V) = \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\odot\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\odot \ldots \odot \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)$ (with $m$ copies) where its dual becomes $\mathbb Z[(\mathbb Z/(m+1)\mathbb Z)^n]$.
Update: Dependence on the choice of a basis
One way of interpreting the claim that $\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\odot \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)$ has an invariant or universal definition would be the assertion that the two-sided ideal $I_{\odot}$ of $\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\otimes \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)$ generated by the element $\{\alpha\wedge e_i\otimes \beta\wedge e_i\}$ is actually independent of the choice of basis $e_i$. (That is, even though the definition manifestly depends on a choice of basis, it is the ideal that is generated by the relations that determines the quotient, not a particular choice of generating set for the ideal).
However, if this claim is true then $\alpha\wedge f\otimes \beta \wedge f \in I_{\odot}$ for any $f\in \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb Z e_i=V$ which can form part of a basis of $V$. But $f=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$  lies in a basis for $V$ precisely when $\text{g.c.d.}(a_i: 1\leq i\leq n)=1$, and of course of $\alpha\wedge f\otimes \beta\wedge f \in I_{\odot}$ so is $\alpha\wedge (kf)\otimes \beta \wedge(kf)$ for any integer $k$, and thus $I_{\odot}$ contains $\alpha\wedge u\otimes \beta \wedge u$ for all $u$ in $M$, and hence $\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\otimes \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)/I_{\odot} = \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)$.
Example:
Consider the case $n=2$. Then $\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $\{e_1,e_1+e_2\}$ are both bases of $V$. If the ideal $I_{\odot}$ generated by $\{e_1\otimes e_1,e_2\otimes e_2\}$ in $\bigwedge\!{^*(}V)\otimes \bigwedge\!{^*(}V)$ was independent of the basis used to define it, then
$$
e_1\otimes e_1, e_2\otimes e_2, (e_1+e_2)\otimes (e_1+e_2) \in I_{\odot},
$$
which implies
$$
\begin{split}
e_1\odot e_2 +e_2\odot e_1 = (e_1&+e_2)\odot(e_1+e_2)\\
&- e_1\odot e_1 - e_2\odot e_2 \in I_{\odot}
\end{split}
$$
and hence $\odot$ is just the wedge product.
Thus it would appear that this is not a construction on $\mathbb Z$-modules, because the algebra one obtain depends on the choice of basis  on the choice of a basis of the $\mathbb Z$-module $V$. If that is correct, then the construction is really a functor on finite rank based abelian group, i.e. finite rank free abelian groups equipped with a choice of basis. But such abelian groups are obtained by applying the functor $\text{Free}$ to an object of the category $\mathbf{FinSet}$ of finite sets, and, in terms of the finite set $X$, the construction is equivalent to the covariant functor $\mathcal T$ where $\mathcal T(X) = \mathbb Z^{\mathbb F_3^X}$, where, on morphisms $\mathcal T$ is given by the following: if $f\colon X\to Y$ then $\mathcal T(f) \colon\ \mathcal T(X)\to \mathcal T(Y)$ is given by
$$
\mathcal T(f)(a)(\phi) = a(f^*(\phi)), \quad \text{ where } a \in \mathcal T(X), \phi\in \mathbb F_3^Y
$$
and where $f^*\colon \mathbb F_3^Y \to \mathbb F_3^X$ is the composition map $\phi\mapsto \phi\circ f$.

Thx for your answer! You probably mean $(\mathbb{Z} /(m+1)\mathbb{Z})^n$, right? (Although I don't understand why you use the notations $\mathbb{Z} /m\mathbb{Z}$ or even $\mathbb{F}_3$ in the first place.) Anyway, I don't really see an argument, why the thing can't be defined coordinate free. I mean, by the same logic $\Lambda V$ itself would be just the dual of $\mathbb{Z}\left[[2]^{[n] }\right]$. However, we all know that it's a bit more than that. Still, I don't exclude the possibility that this is an $m=1$ specialty.

Yes sorry, $\mathbb Z/(m+1)\mathbb Z$ is what I meant. It's true, it just has to be a set with $m+1$ elements, but as you wrote the $m+1=3$ case as ${-1,0,1}$ it seemed natural to call that $\mathbb F_3$. I'll try and think a bit more about whether I believe there can be a coordinate-free definition.
